# How can a company know that I re-used some techniques?

Tags: legal, code-reuse

I'm a software engineer in a company.

However, I'm planning to start a self project very soon.

I wonder if I am allowed to re-use the code I have written in my company product in my project.

It is not going to be the same functionality or feature.

It's just a basic thing.

For example: A way to handle errors on the back-end or send request responses to the front-end, can I use the same technique used ? Not code but the same way those things were handled. ( architecture, classes etc)

And also how would my company know that I have used the same technique they use in a product ?

Like I will have to be lucky that my project doesn't go public and someone who works on the same product doesn't see it ?

Comment: This sounds highly illegal for most companies around

Comment: My advice?  Leave all of the code you wrote for the original company with the original company, and write your own code from scratch.  They own all of the code you wrote.

Comment: Despite the title, the question seems to be about reusing architecture / ideas, which is a significantly different situation.

Comment: When you say "reuse", do you mean copying the company's code (and then altering it if you need to), or building something new from scratch using your knowledge? Morally, there's little difference, but legally there is.

Comment: `A way to handle errors on the back-end or send request responses to the front-end, can I use the same technique used ?` Is there any copyright or patent you might be afraid of? If you are afraid of implementing "ideas" the company should be really afraid of its own activity since they re-use "ideas" and "techniques" all the time. Some might call these ideas "patterns" others "designs" others "principles" or "good practices". Implementing the same idea is not the problem, copying the code is.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. *"can I use the same technique used` Not code"* contradicts to some degree what you wrote a few lines earlier, and "techniques" is an extremely vague term. Reusing "techniques" can be legally ok or not, depends on very much on what you mean by that term.

Answer (score 3):

#### Don't do it !

The probability that you can rightfully reuse for your own purpose some software that you wrote as employee seems extremely low:

- Your employment contract might give ownership or patrimonial rights (i.e. right to use or to sell it) to your employer.
- The law of your country might grant ownership or patrimonial rights  to your employer, even if your contract doesn't explicitly address your point.
- Even in absence of ownership or patrimonial rights, your future ex-company might sue you for unfair competition (since you'd benefit for free from something they paid for).
- In addition to the legal and financial consequences of such litigation, there is a high risk for your reputation. THis could be fatal to your future business

So do not reuse code ! Don't take any risk to do illegal things. Leave your old code to your former employer, and start from scratch with your new activity and your new product.  Or if you reuse it, do it only with the written agreement of your former employer.

#### Sooner or later they'll find out

There are plenty of ways your former employer can discover the situation.  For example, if your new software will produce very specific logs and error messages and someone could notice that these are very similar to those of your former employer. These kind of things are sufficient to start suspicion.  But you could have a common customer.  Or employees who move from one company to the other, etc... The world is smaller than we think. Do you really want to risk sleepless nights  ?

If your former company suspect you, they can start a litigation.  And if there's a litigation, you'll not be able to hide anything in your code.  A judge can order you to remit it to an expert witness/forensic examiner.  In worst case, police could even seize it in your offices !

Don't hope that changing some variable names and these kind of tricks would help to hide the reality.  In his excellent book "*The software IP's detective handbook*", Bob Zeidman, an expert in this matter, explains different techniques to find similarity between different source code and the way it can be used to show that there was software theft. As it is several hundreds of page long, you'll understand that it's a subject too broad for a post on this forum.

***Disclamer:*** I just answered with common sense arguments.  I'm not a lawyer.  For legal advise, consult a lawyer or a qualified legal expert in your jurisdiction.  Don't rely on internet forums for business matters.

Comment: you might want to add that even if its legal, you still don't want to do it for the same reasons. Avoid all suspicion!

Answer (score 0):

I once started a new job, and found code that I had written myself elsewhere. Yes, company A had acquired the rights to B’s software, so it was ok. But it shows things can get found out. “Can I get found out” is a very, very bad thing to base your actions on.

What you can do: Any general knowledge you learn is yours. You can use it to write code again with much less effort than the first time. Just don’t copy anything. If you worry about accusations, keep a git repository with many, many check-ins.